# Codeigniter how can I make this route work

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've looked around in the documentation and a few other places and I am not sure how to achieve the results I want. I have a domain name set up that will only server public profile pages to visitor. When someone comes straight to the site I want it to display a welcome screen telling more about what the website is about. (example.com) When someone visits example.com/my-public-page   I want it to run a default controller that grabs the 'my-public-page from the url, searches the database for a user with that info in a column and displays their info.

I would image that I just set the default_controller to my controller and then check for a second string in the url. If its present search for that in the database. After looking around I am not sure how to make this work and not sure what to search for to get the results I need.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

After defining an encryption key for sessions in config.php you can use something like this:

```
   class Wellcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() { 
        parent::__construct();
        $this -> load -> library('session');
        if(!$this->session->userdata('visit_time')) {
        $this->session->set_userdata('visit_time', time());
        redirect('first_visit'); 
        } 
    } 

}
```